# Магия с Bootstrap?

Tags: wordpress, bootstrap

**WordPress**
После подключение последней версии Bootstrap пропадает меню, но на мобильной версии есть. Само меню подтягивается через шаблон. Если отключить Bootstrap - то меню есть.

P.S. Меню вверху справа

Сайт с траблом:

> www.adv-aura.pro

```css
#site-navigation-wrap {
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue",Helvetica,Arial;
    height: 40px;
    margin-top: -20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div id="site-navigation-wrap">
 <a id="navigation-toggle" href="#sidr-main"><span class="fa fa-bars"></span>Menu</a>
 <nav role="navigation" class="navigation main-navigation clr" id="site-navigation">
  <div class="menu-verh-menyu-container"><ul class="dropdown-menu sf-menu sf-js-enabled" id="menu-verh-menyu"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-4 current_page_item menu-item-195" id="menu-item-195"><a href="http://www.adv-aura.pro/">Головна</a></li>
   <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-206" id="menu-item-206"><a href="http://www.adv-aura.pro/poslugy/" class="sf-with-ul">Послуги</a>
   <ul class="sub-menu" style="display: none;">
   <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-196" id="menu-item-196"><a href="http://www.adv-aura.pro/poslugy/seo/">SEO</a></li>
   <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-199" id="menu-item-199"><a href="http://www.adv-aura.pro/poslugy/kontekstna-reklama/">Контекстна реклама</a></li>
   <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-197" id="menu-item-197"><a href="http://www.adv-aura.pro/poslugy/smm/">SMM</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
   <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-200" id="menu-item-200"><a href="http://www.adv-aura.pro/staty-sty-ka/">Статистика</a></li>
   <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-198" id="menu-item-198"><a href="http://www.adv-aura.pro/kontakty/">Контакти</a></li>
  </ul></div>     
 </nav><!-- #site-navigation -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bootstrap своими стилями к класу dropdown-menu зачеркнул мои стили. Поправил классы - все ок.